# In ruby, how to convert epoch milli seconds into Time Object without losing milli seconds information?

Tags: ruby, date, time

I want to convert epoch milli seconds into Time without losing mill second information. Is it doable?

Comment: give a example of the time format you have

Answer (score 2):

You should use `Time.at` and then `usec` method to get the microseconds of time.

```
epoch_milli = 1479383961245
t = Time.at(epoch_milli / 1000.0) # => 2016-11-17 09:59:21 -0200
micro = t.usec                    # => 244999
milli = micro / 1000.0            # => 244.999
```

Comment: You can use `seconds, milliseconds = epoch_milli.divmod(1000); Time.at(seconds, milliseconds * 1000)` to avoid the floating point error.

Comment: @Stefan Alternatively, `Time.at(epoch_milli / 1000r)` (works in Ruby 2.3.1 at least).

Comment: @Jordan good catch! `Time.at(epoch_milli.quo(1000))` would work, too.

Comment: @Stefan Oh, that's handy. I'll have to remember that.